# How to get the keys if one of key is or '0' in dictionary

Tags: python

I have Dictionary is below, My product output is below. I need to create a new dictionary with two types `Out_1`, `Out_2`

```
product = {'Product1': {'index': '1', '1': 'Book', '2': 'Pencil', '3': 'Pen','value': '1'}, 
 'Product2': {'index': '2', '1': 'Marker', '2': 'MYSQL', '3': 'Scale','value': '0'}}
```

If value inside product is `0` then extract the keys

Expected Output

```
Out_1 = {'Product2': {1:'Marker': '2': 'Compass', '3': 'Scale', 'value': 0}}
Out_2 = {'Product2':['Marker','Compass','Scale', '0']}
```

Psuedo code is below. i tried to create but not able to create as above

```
Out_1 = {}
Out_2 = {i:[]}
for i,j in product.items():
  for a,b in j.items():
    if a['value'] == 0:
       Out_2.append(i)
```

I am getting indices error, How to get `Out_1`, `Out_2`

Comment: your `product` variable is not a valid dict

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish  i have edited,one quote issue, thanks for identifying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the keys if one of key is or '0' in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998329/how-to-get-the-keys-if-one-of-key-is-or-0-in-nested-dictionary)

Comment: Please stop asking questions twice! if they get closed, it is for  reason. Read [ask] and how to provide a [mre] and just ask them once, properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehensions for this.

```
out_1 = {k: v for k, v in product.items() if v['value']=='0'}
out_2 = {k: list(v.values()) for k, v in product.items() if v['value']=='0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi do you really need this index variable? If not yes why would not you use list of dicts instead of dict of dicts. However here is what you wanted:

```py
products = {'Product1': {'index': '1', '1': 'Book', '2': 'Pencil', '3': 'Pen','value': '1'}, 
 'Product2': {'index': '2', '1': 'Marker', '2': 'MYSQL', '3': 'Scale','value': '0'}}

for k,product in products.items():
    product.pop('index', None)
    if product['value'] == '0':
        products[k] = list(product.values())


print(products)
>>> {'Product1': {'1': 'Book', '2': 'Pencil', '3': 'Pen', 'value': '1'}, 'Product2': ['Marker', 'MYSQL', 'Scale', '0']}
```

I was not assigning it to any other variables like out1/2 in case you have more than 2 products

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

**Code:**

```
product = {'Product1': {'index': '1', '1': 'Book', '2': 'Pencil', '3': 'Pen','value': '1'}, 
 'Product2': {'index': '2', '1': 'Marker', '2': 'MYSQL', '3': 'Scale','value': '0'}}
output_1 = {}
output_2 = {}
for key,val in product.items():
    if (val['value'] == '0'):
        output_1[key]=val
        output_2[key]=val.values()
print(output_1)
print(output_2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Product2': {'1': 'Marker', 'index': '2', '3': 'Scale', '2': 'MYSQL', 'value': '0'}}
{'Product2': ['Marker', '2', 'Scale', 'MYSQL', '0']}
```